# How to select rows from today date?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a events table.

I want to select upcoming events.

my table:

**tb_events** has following columns

```
id,event_date,title,location
```

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_events WHERE event_date >= CURDATE()
```

Comment: What for? '>=' actually means 'equal or bigger than'.

Comment: Then I guess your table doesn't contain entries with future dates.

Comment: Or `event_date` is not of date type.

Comment: @Friek - sorry, my bad - I thought the OP was after todays dates.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) docs.